# Need to compare values from two excel sheets(data reconciliation) programmatically and create an output excel file

Tags: python, c#, excel, reconciliation

My requirement:

I need to do reconciliation of two data, ie.., 2 separate Excel sheets(Excel A and Excel B), I need to compare and perform some calculations on multiple columns. Based on that I need to create an output excel (Excel C).

I have licensed VS Studio with me, please help me the best way to proceed with this requirement.I have the following doubts in my mind:

1. Should I use C# or Python (currently the existing is C# for generating Reports )
2. In order to compare is there a necessity to stage these tables in a DB ? If so which one to use ?
3. Can we go ahead with the reconciliations without using a DB Stage? If so please suggest the best easier way .

Please suggest.

I really am confident that I will get very apt solutions here.

Thanks again!

Best,
Jay

Comment: An excel file is a database.  One way to do this is to make an oledb connection to each database and the put results into two c# datatables using a DataAdapter.  the you can compare the two DataTables in c#.

Comment: For the part of reading and comparing the tables, you can use python (pandas). You can work with dataframes if you are familiar with pandas. Read both sheets in A and B with [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) Then compare your data frames and perform your calculations to produce an other dataframe C, then save the result dataframe into an Excel C sheet using [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) .

Comment: @jdweng is there any code samples you could share for me here, in C# to start with -- 
  --- would be of great help.  Thanks